# Adding label into the another window in tkinter using classes

Tags: python, tkinter

Little newbie question but I've started learning Tkinter using classes.
I want to add a label in the new window produced by Button. When I run the code my label exist in the main window, not in the next one.
There's a code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
products = pd.DataFrame({'Type of Product 1': ['1_Product_1', '1_Product_2'],
                'Type of Product 2': ['2_Product_1', '2_Product_2']})

#GUI
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.Button = tk.Button()
        self.Button['text'] = 'Click to see datas'
        self.Button['command'] = self.new_window
        self.Button.pack()
    def new_window(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label['text'] = products
        self.label.pack()
    


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('350x400')
app = App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the `master` for the inner widgets

```
self.Button = tk.Button(self)
```

---

Unrelated to the question that you asked, you should not be calling `tk.Tk()` more than once. If you need more windows, use `tk.Toplevel`.

```
def new_window(self):
    self.root = tk.Toplevel()
    self.label = tk.Label(self.root)
    ...
```